# Equivalent Statements for the Fibre Bundle

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, fibration

Suppose $S$ is a Riemann Surface and $M$ is given as a $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P} (1)-$bundle over $S$ where $ \pi:M \longrightarrow S$ is the corresponding projection.

Is not the previous statement (stated above) equivalent to saying that $(M, \pi, S, \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P} (1))$ is a Fibre Bundle?

Comment: Why would they be different statements?

Comment: It's conceivable that $M$ is tacitly assumed to be equipped with a holomorphic structure for which $\pi$ is a holomorphic map, while a "fibre bundle" (without qualification) to me suggests a (topological) sphere bundle over a $2$-manifold.